# Pesquisar comandos em aplicativos ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Eu utilizava Ubuntu 16.04 com unity. Em todo aplicativo que eu utilizava no sistema, quando precisava utilizar um comando que eu não sabia onde achar, apertava a tecla alt e abria uma barra de pesquisa para que eu pudesse pesquisar qual o comando que eu queria.
Instalei o ubuntu 18.04, que utiliza o gnome e percebi que essa função não existe mais com a tecla alt (que apenas abre o menu 'arquivo', 'editar' etc). Existe outra forma para que eu possa realizar essa pesquisa?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando comando

```
ls ${PATH//:/ }
```

Isso listará todos os comandos em sua variável de ambiente $ PATH.

Para armazenar o resultado em um arquivo, você pode redirecionar a saída para um arquivo.

```
ls ${PATH//:/ } > meusComandos.txt
```